# UIAlertController and UIPopoverController in a Universal App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I am working on a universal app for the iPhone 6S / 6S Plus / and iPad form factors. Normally, presenting actionsheets / alertviews on an iPhone-only app is a simple manner. But my application crashes when I attempt to present these on an iPad, returning the following error:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController () of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'"

It is my understanding that I must display a popover when the application is running on an iPad instead of a conventional actionsheet. For the sake of context, the action sheet is presented by a button in a custom cell, which is in a tableview.

What is the best way to handle UIAlertControllers / Action Sheets / UIPopoverControllers in a universal app?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSString *titleToUse = @"";

//    switch (self.openGroup) {
//        case 0:
//            titleToUse = [self.deviceListData[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"deviceName"];
//            break;
//            
//        case 1:
//            titleToUse = [self.computersData[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"deviceName"];
//            break;
//            
//        case 2:
//            titleToUse = [self.mobileData[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"deviceName"];
//            break;
//            
//        case 3:
//            titleToUse = [self.smartData[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"deviceName"];
//            break;
//            
//        default:
//            break;
//    }

    UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:titleToUse message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        // Cancel button tappped.

    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Get More Info" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        AlertDetailModal *alertDetail = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"alertDetailModal"];

        alertDetail.delegate = self;
        alertDetail.securityLevel = self.securityLevel;

        UINavigationController *modalNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:alertDetail];
        [self presentViewController:modalNavCon animated:YES completion:nil];

    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Bandwidth Profile" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Alert Settings" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Security Settings" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Unblock Connection" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }]];

    // Present action sheet.
    [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The fact that its universal is irrelevant. You setup the alert controller's `popoverPresentationController` the same regardless. It will then display properly on all devices.

In this case you should set the `sourceView` to `tableView` and `sourceRect` to the rect for the selected row.

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:titleToUse message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
actionSheet.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = tableView;
actionSheet.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, very concise and clear answer :)